# Se puede crear un método genérico que devuelva una lista

Tags: c#

Se puede crear un método genérico usando listas que sirva para obtener una colección de datos. Estoy trabajando con SQL Server, app Windows Forms

Con un DataTable si se puede hacer, enviandole la query SQL

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var strSQL = "SELECT Id, Nombre FROM Ejemplos";
        var dt = GetAll(strSQL);
        dgvEjemplo.DataSource = dt;
    }


    private DataTable GetAll(string strSql)
    {
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
        {
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = strSql ;
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    var dt = new DataTable();da.Fill(dt);return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: La lista que quieres devolver puede ser de distintos tipos de objetos?

Comment: @sioesi Asi es, en ese caso un DataTable se presta para eso, sería una de las contra de una lista genérica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generico pensando en algo magico no creo, pero podria ser algo aproximado como ser

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Func<IDataReader, Ejemplo> converted = r=> {
            return new Ejemplo(){
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(r["Id"]),
                Nombre = r["Nombre"].ToString()
            };
        };

        DbHelper helper = new DbHelper();

        var strSQL = "SELECT Id, Nombre FROM Ejemplos";
        List<Ejemplo> result = helper.GetAll<Ejemplo>(strSQL, converted);

    }


}

public class DbHelper
{

    public List<T> GetAll<T>(string strSql, Func<IDataReader, T> convert)
    {
        List<T> result = new List<T>();

        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
        {

            var cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, cn);
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(reader.Read())
            {       
               result.Add(convert(reader));
            }


        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class Ejemplo
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Nombre {get;set;}
}
```

la idea es indicar la clase que quieres retornar y ademas un convertidor de los datos donde defines como mapean los campos del reader con los de la clase

Comment: pero en la pregunta planteas el uso de una lista y ademas dices que sea generica, por descarte es uan lista generica en base a una clase